# Passing parameter to Crystal Report in Windows Forms (VB.net)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports

I am using Visual Studio 2008(vb.net), SQL Server 2008 and Crystal Report 9.

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 
I have added this procedure in Crystal Report Data Expert

Now, I just want to pass a parameter to Crystal Report so that it will show me data in Crystal Report.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim myParameterFields As ParameterFields
Dim myParameterField As ParameterField
Dim myDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue

myParameterFields = New ParameterFields
myParameterField = New ParameterField
myDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue

myParameterField.ParameterFieldName = "@Date"
myDiscreteValue.Value = cj
myParameterField.CurrentValues.Add(myDiscreteValue)

myParameterFields.Add(myParameterField)

myParameterField = New ParameterField
myDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue

CrystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = myParameterFields

CrystalReportViewer1.Refresh()
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = "D:\YOGESH KA PROJECT\stationary\stationary\Forms\BillReport.rpt" ' Assign Report Source to CRV
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim paramDV As New ParameterDiscreteValue()
paramDV.Value = "Parameter Value"
report.ParameterFields("@ParameterName").CurrentValues.Clear()
report.ParameterFields("@ParameterName").DefaultValues.Clear()
report.ParameterFields("@ParameterName").CurrentValues.Add(paramDV)
```

where `report` is your Crystal Report object

Comment: i converted it is not woking bro

Comment: @CHANDRAHAS - "It is not working" isn't very helpful.  Can you add the code the you are using in to your question and the reasons/error messages that describe why it is not working.

Comment: Error 1 Name 'report' is not declared. D:\YOGESH KA PROJECT\stationary\stationary\Forms\PrintReport.vb 28 9 stationary

Comment: @CHANDRAHAS: As I said before, please edit your question and post the code that you are using.